# Scraping for href links

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to collect the specific link on this page with the correct keywords, so far I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
url = 'http://www.thenextdoor.fr/en/4_adidas-originals'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
raw = soup.findAll('a', {'class':'add_to_compare'})
links = raw['href']
keyword1 = 'adidas'
keyword2 = 'thenextdoor'
keyword3 = 'uncaged'
for link in links:
    text = link.text
    if keyword1 in text and keyword2 in text and keyword3 in text:
```

Im trying to extract [this link](http://www.thenextdoor.fr/en/clothing/2042-adidas-originals-Ultraboost-Uncaged-2303002052017.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if all are present with `all()` and if either 1 is present with `any()`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("http://www.thenextdoor.fr/en/4_adidas-originals").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res)

atags = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'add_to_compare'})
links = [atag['href'] for atag in atags]
keywords = ['adidas', 'thenextdoor', 'Uncaged']

for link in links:  
    if all(keyword in link for keyword in keywords):
        print link
```

Output:

```
http://www.thenextdoor.fr/en/clothing/2042-adidas-originals-Ultraboost-Uncaged-2303002052017.html
http://www.thenextdoor.fr/en/clothing/2042-adidas-originals-Ultraboost-Uncaged-2303002052017.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can do it *in one go* using [a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) as an `href` attribute value for `find_all()`:

```
keywords = ['adidas', 'thenextdoor', 'Uncaged']
links = soup.find_all('a',
                      class_='add_to_compare',
                      href=lambda href: all(keyword in href for keyword in keywords))
for link in links:  
    print(link["href"])
```